# How to sort a table based on col names in R?

Tags: r

I have a table created from a data.frame with count function of R . It is basically one row with counts where the row is chromosome number. However the count function does not produce the table in order of chromosome number. How to fix this order. I tried sort and order function but they does not seem to work on a table.

```
dist<- read.table("~/Desktop/file.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
head(dist)
 Gene CHR ALLELE
1  SLC35E2   1    C/T
2     NADK   1    A/C
3    TTC34   1    T/G
4    PEX14   1    C/T
5 TNFRSF1B   1    G/T
6  CROCCP2   1    G/T
uniq_dist<-dist[!duplicated(dist$Gene), ]
dist_mat <- data.frame(uniq_dist[,-1], row.names= uniq_dist[,1])
counts <- table(dist_mat $CHR)
counts 
1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  2 20 21 22  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  X 
21 12 18 16  7 15 11  4 14  4 16 20  4  4  2 23  9 10  8 12  3 12  5 
dim(counts)
[1] 23
class(counts)
"table"
I want to arrange the order of in the chromosome number from 1-22 and then X at the end and then plot using bar plot

So the desired output should be in order of 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  X
21  20  23  9   10  8   12  3   12  12  18  16  7   15  11  4   14  4   16  4   4   2   5
```

How shall I be able to achieve this, am aware of doing it in a dataframe but not not in table, I would like to know it. Thanks

Comment: You can convert to `factor` with levels specified as `unique` values of that column and then do the `table` i.e. `dist_mat$CHR <- factor(dist_mat$CHR, levels=c(1:22, 'X'))`

Comment: It's better if you provide a reproducible example, but I think `counts[order(as.numeric(names(counts)))]` might work.

Comment: Thanks as of now it works for this while with warning for NA introduction but it gives me the desired output and I can plot it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'CHR' column is `ordered`, we can convert the column to `factor` with `levels` specified as `unique` values of 'CHR', and then do the `table`.

```
table(with(dist_mat, factor(CHR, levels= unique(CHR))))
```

If it is not ordered, we can specify the `levels` as in the `order` we want it to appear in the `table`

```
table(with(dist_mat, factor(CHR, levels= c(1:22, 'X'))))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- sample(c(1:22, 'X'), 100, replace=TRUE)
```

OP's method

```
table(v1)
# v1
# 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  2 20 21 22  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  X 
#2  3  5  6  3  4  4  4  7  3  2  5  2  2  4  5  6  4  8  5  6  6  4
```

After converting to `factor`

```
table(factor(v1, levels=c(1:22, 'X')))
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22  X    
# 2  5  5  6  4  8  5  6  6  3  5  6  3  4  4  4  7  3  2  2  2  4  4
```

Comment: it works as well, thanks a lot, I already did and created the plots with this as well, I actually did not think it this way. Many thanks